# How make child element above child element z-index?

Tags: html, css, css-position, parent-child, z-index

All elements should be absolute position!

What needs to be achieved is that the element "child1" (z-index: 3;) is above "child2" (z-index: 2), both should be in the parent div (z-index: 1;).

How to make this possible?

Code:

```css
  #parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#child1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 80px;
  z-index: 3;
}

#child2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  z-index: 2;
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child1">
    <div id="child2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove z-index from child1 and add z-index:-1 to child2

Comment: Temani Afif Thank you for your reply. All elements need to have a z-index...   By seeing you closed the question .., I would ask you to approach the question because I really need this

Comment: read the duplicate to see why the child1 need to have its z-index removed

Comment: I have read that and other posts and tutorials .. maybe someone comes up with some additional idea maybe find a way to solve this with javascript or simply with css or something like that ...

Comment: take the time to read and understand the duplicate. All what you need is there

Comment: In this text the description states that it is not possible...